# lvalue required on incrementing a void pointer even after proper casting

Tags: c, lvalue, memset

I am implementing `memset()` method. Below is the code snippet:

```
void my_memset(void* ptr, int n, size_t size)
{
    unsigned int i;

    for( i = 0; i < size; ++i, ++(char*)ptr )
            *(char*)ptr = n;
}
```

I am getting the [error](http://ideone.com/4EdHd) as:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘void my_memset(void*, int, size_t)’:
prog.cpp:8: error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

When i change the type of ptr from `void*` to `int*`, it [compiles successfully](http://ideone.com/1DUkC).

Why it is asking for lvalue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void my_memset(void* ptr, int n, size_t size)
{
    char *cptr = (char *)ptr;
    char *limit = cptr + size;

    for(; cptr < limit; cptr++) {
        *cptr = n;
    }
}
```

you can't increment through a cast like that, and you shouldn't want to.

Answer (score 2):

The result of a type-casting is not an lvalue. Say,

```
float f = 3.14;
++((int)f);
```

here we're applying `++` operator to an int value, but we don't have an int variable to increment. So in general case, type-casting cannot produce lvalues.

Answer (score 0):

You can't for the same reason you can't do this:

```
++someFunction();
```

or

```
 ++(a + b);
```

The cast is an expression and the results of expressions don't have writable storage.